# Including other people's comments in your answers

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, content-reuse

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64329/360395)

I'm wondering if it's okay to include another person's comments in your answer. See this:
[image: gipsy commented]

---

If the person answering the question were to get their answer accepted because of copying another person's comment into their answer, it seems like that might be "rude" (or some such related adjective) to the commenter. Is this a permissible practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly OK. In fact, you're *encouraged* to incorporate comments into answers. Comments can go away at any time. If somebody wanted to post it as their own answer, they shouldn't have just left it in a comment. It's *always* OK to provide a good answer or improve an existing one.

Also, as [Dan Bron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273503/dan-bron) mentions [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296809/including-other-peoples-comments-in-your-answers/296810?noredirect=1#comment963061_296810):

> With the caveat that *quoted material* (or even paraphrased) **must be attributed**. Or, for the super paranoid, mark the answer community wiki. Then you can't get any reputation from reflected illumination.

Comment: With the caveat that *quoted material (or even paraphrased) **must be attributed*** (full username, ideally with a link to the comment). Or, for the super paranoid, mark the answer community wiki. Then you can't get any reputation from reflected illumination.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clearing that up for me. Also, great example

Comment: Ok, that's cute. +1.